# On what point have not barrels of ink been poured out?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we reconcile the guidance in the global FAQ with the site’s purpose?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/how-do-we-reconcile-the-guidance-in-the-global-faq-with-the-sites-purpose)

Insofar as it is to pertain to Christianity, I think the [standard wording of the SE FAQ](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) is unreasonable. There have been libraries of books written about every angle of the subject matter at hand.

> If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Any question that comes to this site that does not get closed as "Too Localized" is likely to have an entire book already devoted to it. We're just the cliff notes.

Comment: @MarkTrapp VTC'ed

Comment: er, the title should be `At what point have barrels of ink not been poured out?`

Answer (score 3):

Proposal: <strike>Let's not have that wording in our site FAQ.</strike>

**Edit**: I hereby recind this proposal. I've changed my mind. See this post and my second answer for why: [Can we reverse the trend on low quality posts?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/680/687#687)

Comment: I hereby recall this proposal. I've changed my mind. See this post and my second answer for why: [Can we reverse the trend on low quality posts?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/680/687#687)

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to keep that in the FAQ.  However, it could be reworded a bit.

Current wording:

> If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Possible new text:

> If you can imagine an answer to your question that is reasonably sized, then you're question is scoped appropriate.  However, if you can't imagine an answer shorter the length of *an entire book*, you’re asking too much.

The problem comes in that there are questions that are simply too broad.  For these questions, even summary answers would contain an entire book.

Examples

- [What evidence is there that Jesus died on the cross?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/287/what-evidence-is-there-that-jesus-died-on-the-cross)
- [Has the Bible ever lied?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/has-the-bible-ever-lied)
- [What does the Bible say about ecology?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/806/what-does-the-bible-say-about-ecology)

Because of questions like these, I think we need some type of text in the FAQ to support our decisions to close extremely broad topics.

Comment: Gogo meta barrels of ink :P