# Examples of high-quality questions

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

After all of the discussion about [increasing the quality](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/680/can-we-reverse-the-trend-on-low-quality-posts) of [questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question) and [answers](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) on Christianity.SE I am left desiring examples of high-quality questions.

Post examples of high-quality questions here. We will keep a running list to serve as a repository for inspiration.

- [Why are there so many translations of the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/why-are-there-so-many-translations-of-the-bible)
- [Why doesn't the Catholic Bible include all books from Septuagint?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/why-doesnt-the-catholic-bible-include-all-books-from-septuagint)
- [Why does the LDS church (Mormon) put so much more emphasis on the family than most other denominations do?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/why-does-the-lds-church-mormon-put-so-much-more-emphasis-on-the-family-than-m)
- [What is the biblical meaning of “sanctification”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/440/what-is-the-biblical-meaning-of-sanctification)

Answer (score 1):

Questions regarding Doctrine that are focused

- [What is the Biblical basis the for Immutable Nature of God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4169/what-is-the-biblical-basis-the-for-immutable-nature-of-god)
- [What did the Dominicans have against the immaculate conception?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/what-did-the-dominicans-have-against-the-immaculate-conception)
- [Distributism and Subsidiarity beyond the counsel of Jethro in the Bible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4005/distributism-and-subsidiarity-beyond-the-counsel-of-jethro-in-the-bible)
- [What is the Calvinist view of God's sovereignty?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4098/what-is-the-calvinist-view-of-gods-sovereignty)

Excellent factual questions:

- [What is the earliest name ascribed to the book of Revelation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3902/what-is-the-earliest-name-ascribed-to-the-book-of-revelation)
- [How are Catholic priests chosen and assigned to specific parishes?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-are-catholic-priests-chosen-and-assigned-to-specific-parishes)
- [Was C. S. Lewis a "muscular" Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4068/was-c-s-lewis-a-muscular-christian)
- [What are the differences between the translation ideologies of the NASB and ESV?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/what-are-the-major-differences-between-nasb-and-esv)

Exegetical questions that are focused on doctrine.

- [Calvinist perspective on Luke 18:18-30](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4099/calvinist-perspective-on-luke-1818-30)
- [What is the biblical justification for permitting female pastors?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-is-the-biblical-justification-for-permitting-female-pastors)

I may be a bit biased on that last one, since it's my own post.  It might not be an *excellent* question since it's been retrofitted to the new standards.  Tough call.  (But I was short on good exegetical questions.)