# What about my other questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, asking-questions, questions

This is a post for reference from the [FAQ](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq).

There are some questions that are off-topic on this site.
Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:

- *Questions asking for all views on a broad subject.*
  Questions asking for multiple viewpoints become a scoping issue.  That is, if a question is asking for all viewpoints on the understanding of a broad topic, the question itself is too broad and needs to be narrowed.  If the question is asking about the viewpoints from a narrow topic, the question is constructive for this site.

  If you feel that a question is too broad, it is better to ask about a small number of views in particular and how they relate, rather than asking about all possible views.
- *What the Bible says about a certain subject*
  While this may seem counter-intuitive, the problem with questions like "What does the Bible say about ?" is that these are actually doctrinal questions.  These questions *can* and *should* be asked, as long as you provide a doctrinal framework for these questions.  Otherwise, these questions are asking for a doctrinal interpretation without specifying a doctrinal viewpoint.

  [There is a meta post explaining this more clearly.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/769/84)
- *Pastoral advice questions.*
  If your personal story is required background in order to ask a question, you should consider taking the issue to your pastor or priest. In the same way that SE sites cannot provide legal or medical advice, this is not a good source for personal spiritual advice.

  [There is a meta post specific to this issue as well.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/30)
- *Who are the real Christians?*
  Questions may be asked about any self-proclaimed Christian tradition, but this is not the place to settle who is ultimately right or wrong.

  There is not just [one](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/880/30) but [two](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/what-is-the-definition-of-christian) very relevant meta posts.

Comment: I wish I could +100 for the Pastoral advice questions bullet point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a good reminder that not all questions are well suited or allowed here. We are not trying to be all things to all people or a be-all-and-end-all reference, only a place for really good focused question and answers.