# Are questions about Jehovah's Witnesses on topic?

Tags: discussion

While Jesus Christ appears to be an important part of JW doctrine, I’m not sure Jehovah’s Witnesses fit the general description of a Christian denomination (assuming Christian implies the doctrinal teachings point to Jesus as a Savior; JW doctrine as far as I know considers him to be more of a prophet). I have seen questions about Jehovah’s Witnesses on this site before, usually comparing their doctrine to that of other denominations. Is it on topic to ask questions purely about JW doctrine? If not, which other site would be best suited for those kinds of questions?

Comment: This site's main purpose is about describing the beliefs of groups that call themselves "Christian". JW's call themselves Christian, so what they believe *is* on-topic.

Comment: Makes sense.  I didn't know for sure that they considered themselves Christian (considering the lessened emphasis on Christ)

Comment: The *real* problem is that we **should** have denominational specific stack exchanges (Catholicism, JW, LDS, Rosicrucian, etc).  Unfortunately there are not enough active members of each denomination to support this. So, the solution is to tag the questions with the appropriate denomination and respectfully commingle like good Christians ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes.** This question has come up before several times, and the consensus has been that Jehovah's Witnesses are "Christians" for the purposes of this site. See:

- [What is "mainstream Christianity"?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/884/21576)
- [Who is a Christian for this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/880/21576)

It boils down to any group that self-identifies as "Christian" is on-topic here (see the accepted answer to the first question and Affable Geek's answer to the second).

Comment: Agreed, additionally the posts [Christianity.SE vs Survivor](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/132/christianity-se-vs-survivor?s=1|0.9744) and [how we are different from other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=1|1.9111) help to explain a little bit more of the philosophy behind that decision.