# Can a question ask for Biblical basis without specifying a Bible or type of Bible?

Tags: discussion, bible, bible-quotes, biblical-basis-questions

From this [meta question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth):

> An acceptable question can also ask for the origin of a particular
>   belief, doctrine, or practice.
>
> Bad: Is drinking alcohol a sin?
>
> There are countless answers to this question. Some believe all alcohol
>   is a sin, others think it's permissible only for medicinal purposes,
>   or during communion, and others yet have no restrictions on the
>   consumption of alcohol. Which is the correct answer? We don't know. We
>   can't handle the Truth.
>
> Good: What is the Biblical basis for claiming that drinking alcohol is
>   a sin?
>
> There is a well defined answer to this question. And you don't have to
>   even agree with the conclusion that alcohol consumption is a sin to
>   understand the Biblical basis for the claim.

But which or what type Bible? Catholic Bibles have more books than other Bibles. The translations and wordings might be different.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what type of Bible, as long as it is one recognized by people fit [this site's definition of Christian](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/880/who-is-a-christian-for-this-site).

So, King James, NIV, clatholic, etc, would all be fine.  [The Satanic Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Satanic_Bible) would not.

Comment: Huh? I think I can argue against this the same way the site argues against Truth Questions. Since the site is secular, I believe a type of Bible must be indicated otherwise we could have different answers. One coming from a Catholic Bible that isn't found in a King James Bible.