# Who is this site for?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

In [my answer to the Proposed FAQ question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/proposed-faq-changes/562#562), I mentioned the first line of the FAQ should clearly state who the site is for. Examples on other sites:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq): Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.
- [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq): Gaming - Stack Exchange is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices.
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq): Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in conceptual questions on software development.

We've had a lot of discussion about [who is an expert](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/501/who-is-an-expert-and-where-are-they), the [role of non-believers on the site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/the-role-of-the-non-believer-on-the-site), and [who is a Christian](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/christianity-se-vs-survivor), but we really need to define who exactly the *audience* is.

So who is this site for? The [placeholder FAQ](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> Christianity - Stack Exchange is for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more.

Is this still applicable? Does it need to be changed?

Answer (score 10):

No, I think that's actually a pretty good explanation of what this site's here for.

Comment: I agree.  I think this wording is nice because it specifically excludes those who are looking to tear down Christianity or find holes in it.  It's the people who are earnest about their search.  I can't think of a better way to word it myself.